# Replace android default sqlite build

Tags: java, android, sqlite, wrapper

I would like to replace android default sqlite build for a new one having [rtree](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) feature enabled. It looks like I have to use a java wrapper to accomplish that and the only one I found android compatible was [sqlite4java](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/). I prefer sticking with standards. Unfortunately I found out jdbc is not supported in dalvikvm (Androids VM) and native android.database.sqlite works with an rtree disabled build of sqlite.

Currently I have a new .so sqlite rtree enabled library compiled for android but would like to substitute androids native one without having to use a third party wrapper like sqlite4java. Any ideas? I was thinking about downloading android.database.sqlite package from android sdk and building a jar to substitute only the .so load withing my application context. Is that the best approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was thinking about downloading android.database.sqlite package from android sdk and building a jar to substitute only the .so load withing my application context. Is that the best approach?

So long as you are willing to refactor all necessary classes into your own package, that is probably your only approach. For example, that is what SQLCipher for Android does. They cloned [~37 classes from `android.database` and `android.database.sqlite`](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/tree/master/src/net/sqlcipher) and modified them to use their own SQLCipher-enabled build of SQLite.

Comment: Seems to be much more complicated than I thought. Could not find some `System.loadLibrary` to replace in android's native code. Think I'll be giving up.